# Coding a prediction interval from a generalized additive model with a very large dataset

Tags: r, memory, bigdata, prediction, mgcv

I have a small dataset of people, thier locations, and whether or not they know each other.  It is a subset of a dataset with 1000 people.  Given that each person could know any other person, the number of potential links grows just under n^2.  I want to fit a model with the small subset, to get probability of linkage as a function of distance, so that I can perform simulations with the wider dataset.

I've got two problems:

1. I'm not sure how to create a prediction interval from a fitted GAM object.
2. Generating a prediction interval using either [posterior simulation](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Prediction-interval-with-GAM-td3460175.html) or using [this technique](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2010q2/003585.html) from R-sig-mixed is computationally prohibitive.

The following is an example of my problem, generating the interval using the technique from R-sig-mixed.  Be warned that the last step will throw an error about not being able to allocate a huge vector, unless you're on a really impressive machine.

```
#Some fake location data
set.seed(13)
x = runif(50)*2
y = runif(50)*2
d = cbind(ID = 1:50,as.matrix(dist(data.frame(x,y))))
```

I want to model links as a function of distance.  More fake data:

```
library(reshape)
mdata <- melt(as.data.frame(d), id=c("ID"),measure.vars = colnames(d)[2:ncol(d)],variable.name="distance") 
mdata$popularity = rnorm(25,sd=.3)
colnames(mdata)[colnames(mdata)=="variable"] = "knows"
colnames(mdata)[colnames(mdata)=="value"] = "distance"
mdata = subset(mdata,ID!=knows)
a = exp(1/(mdata$distance/runif(nrow(mdata))^mdata$distance)+mdata$popularity+rnorm(nrow(mdata),sd=.001))
mdata$prlink = a/(1+a)
with(mdata,plot(distance,prlink))
mdata$link = runif(nrow(mdata))<mdata$prlink
mdata$ID = as.factor(mdata$ID)
mdata$knows = as.factor(mdata$knows)
mdata$dum=1 #this facilitates predicting from the population of the model, later
```

Now, I model the data:

```
library(mgcv)
mod = gam(link~s(distance)+s(ID,bs="re",by=dum)+s(knows,bs="re",by=dum),data=mdata,family=binomial(link="logit"))
plot(mod,pages=1)
summary(mod)
```

Now, I want to apply the fitted model to my main dataset:

```
x = runif(1000)*2
y = runif(1000)*2
d = cbind(ID = 1:1000,as.matrix(dist(data.frame(x,y))))
mdata <- melt(as.data.frame(d),id.vars = "ID") 
colnames(mdata)[colnames(mdata)=="variable"] = "knows"
colnames(mdata)[colnames(mdata)=="value"] = "distance"
mdata = subset(mdata,ID!=knows)
mdata$dum=0; mdata$ID=1; mdata$knows=2 #These are needed for prediction, even though I am predicting from the population of the model, not one of the levels.
```

Some timekeeping tools...

```
tic <- function(gcFirst = TRUE, type=c("elapsed", "user.self", "sys.self"))
{
   type <- match.arg(type)
   assign(".type", type, envir=baseenv())
   if(gcFirst) gc(FALSE)
   tic <- proc.time()[type]         
   assign(".tic", tic, envir=baseenv())
   invisible(tic)
}

toc <- function()
{
   type <- get(".type", envir=baseenv())
   toc <- proc.time()[type]
   tic <- get(".tic", envir=baseenv())
   print(toc - tic)
   invisible(toc)
}
tic()
p = predict(mod,newdata=mdata,type="response")
toc()
```

Just predicting the point estimates takes 31 seconds on my machine.  Now to try to get the prediction intervals, first get the design matrix...

```
tic()
Designmat = predict(mod,newdata=mdata,type="lpmatrix")
toc()
```

That took me 47 seconds and froze my computer while it was working.

Now here is the technique for getting a prediction interval that I found on R-sig-mixed...

## CAUTION:  THE FOLLOWING CODE WILL ATTEMPT TO ALLOCATE A MASSIVE AMOUNT OF MEMORY AND MIGHT CRASH YOUR MACHINE.

```
tic()
predvar <- diag(Designmat %*% vcov(mod) %*% t(Designmat))
SE <- sqrt(predvar) 
SE2 <- sqrt(predvar+mod$sig2) 
tfrac <- qt(0.975, mod$df.residual)
interval = tfrac*SE2
toc()

>Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7435.7 Gb
```

Is there another way???

Comment: You only need the diagonal, so think about how you can calculate `diag(A %*% B)`, without calculating `A %*% B`. Btw, are you aware of `system.time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to avoid calculating `Designmat %*% vcov(mod) %*% t(Designmat)`. You only need the diagonal after all. Try this:

```
tmp <- Designmat %*% vcov(mod)

library(compiler)
diagMult <- cmpfun(function(m1, m2) sapply(seq_len(nrow(m1)), 
                                            function(i) m1[i,] %*% m2[,i]))
predvar <-  diagMult(tmp, t(Designmat))
```

(Not tested thoroughly. The function should be implemented with Rcpp to improve speed, if there is not already a compiled version in some package.)

Comment: That works pretty well!  If you get a chance, could you maybe provide a bit of intuition about why it works and what Rcpp does?  No CS training here, only stats.

Comment: Well, it should be obvious. The difference is between calculating the diagonal of a huge matrix product directly (size n in memory) and calculating the whole matrix product (size n^2 in memory). [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) isn't used, but could substantially speed up the operation. (No CS training here, either.)

Comment: Clearly.  I was asking about the compilers library and the cmpfun way of doing a function.

Comment: `cmpfun` compiles the function body. Sometimes you get a bit better performance with compiled functions. But of course this approach can't compete with native C/C++ code.